# Mysql find_in_set + instr

Tags: mysql, string-matching

I have to do something specific in MySql. I have to find in set but not exactly the same string, something like instr

```
find_in_set('use', 'house,useful,full,something')
```

something like this, will return true because have one in set that contains text 'use'

now imagine use an array of values and return only those that contain one of all

```
find_in_set('some,use', 'house,useful,full,something')
```

will return house,useful,something but not full all this is need it for statistics

Maybe I need explain better

```
   urls
id . url
1  . www.guugle.com
2  . www.some.edu.uy
3  . www.yahuu.com.es
4  . www.any.edu.us
```

Now I want count which has .com and how many have .edu

```
select count(case when instr(url,'.edu') then id end) urlsdotedu from urls;
```

that will count all that have .edu extension but imagine that you have 30 sub text and for example count together gov and guv extensions, that will be a very complex select so I trying to find some like find_in_set + instr

Comment: Why not just `LIKE '%use%'`?

Comment: Your edit doesn't really clarify the problem. Do you have something like `foo.edu.bar,a.b.edu` and you want to count that twice? `find_in_set()` doesn't do that, it just returns the index of the first match.

Comment: You really shouldn't use comma-separated lists, it makes things very difficult in SQL. Normalize your schema.